# Confusing Struct Definitions & References Degrading Performance

Tags: c, pointers, optimization, struct

I've been working on an issue where I need to optimize a piece of code for speed, and came across some struct definitions / references that confused me. I was hoping someone could explain the code below or point out any areas where the definitions may not be optimal.

There are 3 relevant snippets of code as far as I can tell. I've had trouble keeping track between CycArr, cyc_inf, and CycInf, and was wondering if there was a smarter way to declare *proc.

```
#if 0
static struct cycles c_start[PROC_CNT][CPU_CNT];
static struct cycles c_end[PROC_CNT][CPU_CNT];
#else
static CycArr c_start;
static CycArr c_end;
#endif
```

... definitions of structs

```
struct cyc_inf
{
   int var1;
   int var2;
   int var3;
}

typedef struct cyc_inf CycInf;
typedef CycInf CycArr [PROC_CNT][CPU_CNT];
```

... the nested for loops is where the speed drops, making me think there's a better way to use cyc_inf proc.

```
void function(int foo) 
{
     struct cyc_inf *proc[PROC_CNT + CPU_CNT];

     if (foo)
         proc = c_start;
     else
         proc = c_end;

     for (int i=0; i<= PROC_CNT; i++)
     {
         for (int j=0; j<= CPU_CNT; j++)
         {
             proc[i][j].var1 = global1[j];
             proc[i][j].var2 = global2[j];
             proc[i][j].var3 = global3[j];
             ...
         }
     } 
}
```

... I have tried aligning the struct but didn't see any improvements. Is there a way to use malloc that is better? Any and all input is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you want our help, then it would behoove you to post code that genuinely demonstrates the problem.  We generally ask for an [mcve], but at minimum you should present code that actually compiles.  Yours does not.  Not even close, really.

Comment: I understand. I intentionally stripped out details I saw as unnecessary, and left the most basic form of the code snippets in question. My intention is not to make this code compile-able but rather find a better way to define the structs in question and define *proc.

Comment: Posting   `#if 0
static struct cycles c_start[PROC_CNT][CPU_CNT];
static struct cycles c_end[PROC_CNT][CPU_CNT];
#else` adds unnecessary code.

Comment: I see 3 goals: 1) explain the code, 2)  point out any areas where ... not be optimal. 3)   if there was a smarter way to declare *proc.  Which one is most important?  If you want #2, you _must_ post compile-able code. A [MCVE] is useful in all cases.

Comment: By posting code that *is* compilable, you A) make sure that all relevant code is in the question B) make sure that you don't have typos like `c_stop` when you meant `c_end` C) make sure that the code is actually valid C code, unlike `proc[][].var1`. So your intention *should* be to post compile-able code.

Comment: May I ask - if you're assigning the same 3 globals to all procs, why do you need var1/var2/var3 at all? Can't you just read these values directly from the globals when you need them? Might they change later?

Comment: @chux I think just #3 would be helpful. I can see why the other questions may be more difficult to answer given how vague I was in my post. proc[i][j].var1/2/3 end up being written thousands of times in my loops. Is there a different way to define *proc that may localize / make access to it faster? Is there any other way besides align() to ensure cache locality? Thanks everyone sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @SHG Missed the [j] on my globals. They are all different. Sorry about that.

Comment: Still, every time you need the global value of `proc[i][j].var1` (for any i) just use `global1[j]`. Why do you need to copy the globals' values?

Comment: @user3768274 please add a link to the complete code so we can compile, test, and debug it for ourselves